# Imagenes rotas bootstrap

Tags: php, bootstrap, navbar

primera vez preguntando algo y novato con esto del `Bootstrap`, tengo un problema que al mostrar imágenes en el `header` (`navbar-brand`) muestra imágenes rotas me he asegurado de que la ruta y la extensión de la imagen es la correcta, la imagen es de menor tamaño que el `header` y sin mas les dejo el código:

De antemano muchas gracias

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{{url('/')}}">
                        <img src="..\img\logo1.img" class="img-responsive">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema debe estar en la extensión del archivo, debe ser `.jpg` `.png` o `.svg` ya que los archivos con extensión `.img`, según wikipedia, *son archivos binarios que almacenan imágenes de disco...* [consulta la referencia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMG_(formato_de_archivo))

Prueba cambiando la extensión de los archivos tanto en el código como a la imagen.

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{{url('/')}}">
   <img src="../img/logo1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
</a>
```

Comment: he notado ese error y lo arreglé como dices pero aun sigo con las imagenes rotas

Comment: @HarambePeng Puedes agregar en tu pregunta una captura de pantalla donde nos muestres la ruta de tus imágenes y la ruta del archivo que las invoca?

Comment: Deberías usar "../img/logo1.jpg" esta barra /  en lugar de \. Y en todo caso chequear que logo1.jpg no sea en realidad logo1.JPG.

Comment: @SolucionesPyMESyHogares tienes absoluta razón, gracias por la corrección. Edité la respuesta con la sugerencia de _Soluciones PyMES y Hogares_.

Answer (score 0):

La solucion era utilizar el helper "asset" `{{ asset('img/logo1.png') }}`

Comment: Me alegra que encontraras la solución. Por curiosidad, ¿qué es o qué hace el helper "asset"? ¿por qué al usarlo se soluciona el problema?